# Android Text on Button not showing with Strings.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am tryign to set a simple string for a button in my application. I could button.setText("text") in my oncreate but thats TOO much. I just want my button text to show. I set the button1 string in my strings.xml file to be a text, but it doesn't want to show. The XML graphic view shows that the button has @strings/button1 as its text on the button.

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
        android:text="@strings/button1" />
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">couchto5k</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>

<string name="button1">ONE</string>


</resources>
```

Comment: If you are using Eclipse IDE use crtl+space. Can you post those code which is working fine with @strings/text

Comment: Try this way : button1.setText(getString(R.string.button1));

Answer (score 1):

Remove s from Strings. It is just @string

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
    android:text="@string/button1" />
```

Comment: I had used @strings/text in other programs and it worked then as well. Its weird.

Comment: @Jayizzle is the layout displayed. THe button displays without text?

Answer (score 0):

In your xml layout replace  `android:text="@strings/button1"` with  `android:text="@string/button1"`. It is **string** NOT **strings** .
Alternatively you can use

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setText("Hi There");
```

in your onCreate() method.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
        android:text="@string/button1" />
```

try this, it should be @string and not @strings